# Describing internal function via JSDoc

Tags: jsdoc

I have such code:

```js
var f = function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.keyA = "val";
    obj.keyB = function(arg2){}
    return obj;
}
```

`arg2` is a {string}.

Is it possible to describe this code fine using JSDoc?

As you see, this code is attemption to implement smth like an object-oriented code. It is because I should work with old JavaScript engine (ECMA 262 Edition 3, parts of Edition 4, 5 and 6). It seems, this engine does not support classes (an interpreter thrown a syntax error).

So, is it possible to describe the code above in a way that JSDoc generates readable documentation?

Comment: Why bother documenting `arg2` if it isn't used?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a custom tag `typedef` which will allow you to describe inner type in the first place e.g.

```
/**
 * Definition for keyB
 * @callback KeyBCallback
 * @param {*} arg2
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * Definition of an internal obj
 * @typedef {Object} InternalObj
 * @property {string} keyA - some property
 * @property {KeyBCallback} keyB - a callback stored in keyB
 */
```

Lastly, you need to put `InternalObj` as a return value for your function e.g.

```
/**
 * Function f
 * @returns {InternalObj}
 */
var f = function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.keyA = "val";
    obj.keyB = function(arg2){}
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: keyB isn't a callback, it is just a function and should be documented as such. OP said that `arg2` is a string so why use `*` and not `string` in the param block?